# MYSQL Set 1 field to equal another field - but add text

Tags: mysql, set

I'm wondering if there's a way to use
    `update your_table
     set B = A`

But I'd like to add some numbers at the front

So it's more like
    `update your_table
    set B = ('00',A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table 
set B = concat('00', A)
```

Answer (score 0):

This represents bad relational data storage practice. Rather than duplicating data which may result in headaches later (you now need to update two columns to change one set of data) you should concatenate the results upon retrieval.

Comment: It was to update an area already populated - there was a step missed - and unfortunately column B was missed out by mistake. This was the only way

Comment: So why not update the field rather than copying it and THEN updating it?

Comment: Column A has no 0's - Column B had to have Column A with 0's. ColumnB was supposed to be done initially, but was missed out by mistake, so the quickest way was to just quickly set Column B as above.